# Op Amp Power Calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, power

[image: culation]

I am simulating an op-amp circuit of which a small section is shown in the image. As  per power consumption formula,

P = Icc * (V+ - V-) + Iout * (V+ - Vout)

I tried to calculate the power. I have put the values shown in the image.

P = 1.17mA (I have confusion in this value) * (5V-(-5v)) + 0.36 mA (5V-2.16V)

P = 11.7 mW +   1.0224 mW = 12.72mW. But the Watt meter probe in simulation shows 4.89mW .

I got a confusion that whether I am missing any point or doing wrong in the calculation?

Clarify this!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the three currents that this opamp is sinking/sourcing:

- Sinking \$I_4 = 98.3\mu A\$ via the +ve power pin (4)
- Sourcing \$I_{11} = 1.10mA\$ via the -ve power pin (11)
- Sourcing \$I_7 = 192\mu A\$ via the output pin (7)

To be honest, I don't understand how your simulator is reporting a negative current in pin 4. The relationship between the sign and the green current arrow doesn't make sense to me. I'll have to just go with my gut on this. It could be that the output is actually sinking current from a much more positive supply.

By Kirchhoff's Current Law we should have

$$ I_4 = I_7 + I_{11} $$

but we don't. The only reason I can think of is that the other three opamps in the LM2901 package all share the same power supply. Each is sinking and sourcing current via their own outputs, and each is sinking/sourcing its own share of total supply current, all via pins 4 and 11.

This would mean you cannot use the values from your schematic, in isolation, to calculate the power in this particular opamp unit. In fact, you cannot calculate the power dissipated by any individual opamp in the package without knowing the exact current it is drawing for itself from the power supply, *and* sinking sourcing via its output; that is, how much of the total power supply current is due to that particular unit, at that particular instant in time.

The [LM2902 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902.pdf?ts=1634258969200) gives you a rough idea of the total current drawn from the power supply, which is about 1mA. Assuming that all four opamps are completely independent, sharing no circuitry, you can estimate that each one draws about a quarter of that, 250μA.

With outputs on pins 8 and 14 sinking current, and outputs on pins 1 and 7 sourcing, this is how you might visualise the LM2902 holistically, and each unit inside it individually:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsysHw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Estimating the power dissipated by unit B, which would be the sum of operating power and power in the upper output transistor:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= (+5V - (-5V)) \times 250\mu A + (5V - 2.16V) \times 192\mu A \\
&= 10V \times 250\mu A + 2.84V \times 192\mu A \\
&= 3mW
\end{aligned}
$$

That's much closer to your simulated value of 4.8mW. We've made a few assumptions though, like that pin 7 is sourcing current, and the total unloaded supply current for all opamps is 1mA.

Answer (score 0):

Power consumption of the op amp is different than the power drawn from the supply.

The equation below should give you the power consumed by the op amp I think.

ICC * VCC + IEE * VEE - I(OUT) * V(OUT)

Comment: Tip: You can use HTML entities such as `&times;` (\$ \times \$) and some markdown such as `<sub>...</sub>` and `<sup>...</sup>` for sub- and superscript.

Comment: Thank you I was wondering how people were doing that

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the various measurements - DC, p-p and RMS - but just working with the DC I get:

[image]

1. 5.5 mW is provided by V<sub>EE</sub>.
2. -0.49 mW is provided by V<sub>DC2</sub>. I'm not sure how a circuit could do this.
3. The output current is negative so the op-amp is sinking current so power out is -0.41 mW.

Adding them up I get P<sub>IC</sub> = P<sub>IN</sub> - P<sub>OUT</sub> = (5.5 - 0.49) + (-0.41) = 4.6 mW.

That's the best I can make of it.